# Rails 5.2 some controller actions gives InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: csrf, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Previously I used a gem which provided a controller for accepting external services to POST some data into our app. However in Rails 5.2 it stopped working. When the endpoint is triggered, it raises `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Rails before 5.2, the generated ApplicationController will call `protect_from_forgery`, meaning POST,PUT,DELETE actions are checked for authenticity.

New Rails 5.2 projects will [by default check authenticity token for any subclass of **ActionController::Base**](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ec4a836919c021c0a5cf9ebeebb4db5e02104a55) instead, which affects many existing Gems.

You can wait for the gem updates for compatibility with 5.2.

Alternatively, you can probably monkey patch these controllers in the initializer:

```
require 'foo_controller'
class FooController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, raise: false
end
```

Comment: That worked for me, but isn't it effectively removing the csrf protection?

Comment: @ardochhigh if you are faced with this issue you aren't protected in those controllers prior to the upgrade. And those gems being affected may not have a access to token in the first place (e.g. external posting endpoint)

Comment: This worked for me. Braintree posts webhooks to a controller action and won't have access to the CSRF token, so i'm forced to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too using destroy_user_session_path in sign out link. I compared my older app (rails 5.1.x) vs this newly built rails 5.2.0, I noticed that I didn't have `csrf_meta_tags` in  tag of my layout.

After adding

`= csrf_meta_tags`

it worked! HTH

`ruby '2.3.5'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'`