# Rails 5.2 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

After upgrading to Rails 5.2 I started to get an **ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken** error for all forms in my application. I have worked around this by disabling Turbolinks for all forms, which works but is not a very good solution.

Seaarching the internet, the common solution recommended seems to be to disable **protect_from_forgery**

`skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, raise: false`

- https://github.com/ForestAdmin/forest-rails/pull/254
- [Rails 5.2 some controller actions gives InvalidAuthenticityToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762136/rails-5-2-some-controller-actions-gives-invalidauthenticitytoken)
- https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/208
- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ec4a836919c021c0a5cf9ebeebb4db5e02104a55

Why would we need to disable **protect_from_forgery**, and doesn't that create a security hole ?

**EDIT**

`csrf_meta_tags` are in the layout.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For Rails 5.2 `default_protect_from_forgery` is [enable by default](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ec4a836919c021c0a5cf9ebeebb4db5e02104a55) on `ActionController::Base`.

You can disable it using the following syntax as explained [in the PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ec4a836919c021c0a5cf9ebeebb4db5e02104a55).

```
config.action_controller.default_protect_from_forgery = false
```

Ref from the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html):

> config.action_controller.default_protect_from_forgery determines whether forgery protection is added on ActionController:Base. This is false by default, but enabled when loading defaults for Rails 5.2.

Comment: Thank you for this, but if this is set, isn't the app now open to csrf attacks?

Comment: You can use `protect_from_forgery` in your `ApplicationController`. If it generates the error again then you may have missed meta tags somewhere, maybe in an AJAX call

Comment: The default is set on `ActionController::Base` and that is why if some external library you are using might be causing the error. Setting `protect_from_forgery` in `ApplicationController` will make your controllers safe.

Answer (score 2):

For rails 5.2 I had to add these to lines inside controller I had a issue:

```
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, raise: false
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized
```

and it worked in my case.

Comment: Using just the first line worked for me